# Что такое формальные и фактические параметры,входные и выходные параметры

Tags: c

Можете показать на этом примере , где находятся вышеуказанные вещи ?

```
#include <stdio.h>
void swap(int *x, int *y);

int main(void)
{
  int i, j;

  i = 10;
  j = 20;

  printf("i и j перед обменом значениями: %d %d\n", i, j);

  swap(&i, &j); /* передать адреса переменных i и j */

  printf("i и j после обмена значениями: %d %d\n", i, j);

  return 0;
}

void swap(int *x, int *y)
{
  int temp;

  temp = *x;  /* сохранить значение по адресу x */
  *x = *y;    /* поместить y в x */
  *y = temp;  /* поместить x в y */
}
```

Это ,кстати,передача по ссылке ? верно ?

Comment: В C нет передачи по ссылке. Есть передача указателя по значению.

Comment: @VladD: Понятие "передачи по ссылке" является надъязковым и появилось задолго до появления С++-ных ссылок. Слово "ссылка" в "передача по ссылке" никакого отношения к С++-ных ссылкам не имеет, а подразумевает лишь способ передачи, в котором из процедуры/функции можно получить доступ к исходному объекту. В С, разумеется, есть передача по ссылке. Куда ж без нее? Передача по ссылке в С реализуется через передачу указателя на объект. То же самое относится и к концепции "входных" и "выходных" параметров.

Comment: @AnT: Не согласен. Передача по ссылке _эмулируется_ на C при помощи передачи указателя по значению. Точно так же как классы _эмулируются_ структурами и указателями на функции. Точно так же как функции _эмулируются_ макросами. Но то, что классы можно сэмулировать в C, не означает, что они там _есть_.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71144/discussion-on-question-by-elvin-------).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Формальные параметры — это переменные внутри функции, которые будут содержать передаваемое снаружи при вызове значение. В современных версиях C они описываются в *деклараторе* функции:

```
int f(int a, void* b) { ... }
```

Здесь `int a` и `void* b` — декларация формальных параметров.

Фактические параметры, также называемые *аргументами* функции — переменные или выражения, которые должны быть упомянуты при вызове функции, и которые определяют начальные значения переменных-параметров при этом выполнении функции. Для вызова `f(x + 1, p)` это соответственно выражения `x + 1` и `p`.

Входные параметры — это те, которые обязательно должны иметь значение, и изменения которых не видны снаружи. Соответственно, их значением может быть выражение.

Выходные параметры — это те, которые не обязательно должны иметь присвоенное значение перед вызовом функции, но которым функция должна обязательно присвоить значение, и это присвоенное значение будет «видно» вызывающему коду. Соответственно, их значением может быть только переменная (lvalue).

В C все параметры входные, выходных параметров нет.

---

(Я намеренно не разбираю конкретно ваш пример, т. к. он выглядит как учебное задание. Всё необходимое для понимания кода, приведённого в вопросе, в ответе есть.)

Comment: Можете по-другому объяснить входные и выходные параметры ?

Comment: @Elvin: Эээ, а как по-другому? Входные — это те, которые попадают внутрь функции, но не выходят наружу. Выходные — это те, которые выходят наружу, а внутрь попадает лишь переменная для них.

Comment: Что значит : не видны снаружи ? можете привести пример ?

Comment: @Elvin: Пусть у нас есть функция `void f(int x) { x = x + 10; }`. Вызываем: `int v = 100; f(v); /*тут v всё ещё равно 100*/`.

Comment: Значит , функция скопировала значение сто в икс ,но не изменяет оригинальный v ?

Comment: @Elvin: да, именно так.

Comment: а если бы  передавал адреса аргументов(в фактическом, из главной программы , то есть пользовался & ) и принимал , и объявлял их  в подпрограмме  указателями , то это то же входные параметры ?

Comment: @Elvin: То тогда эти адреса и были бы входными параметрами.

Answer (score 1):

Из стандарта C11:

> **argument
>  actual argument
>  actual parameter (deprecated)**
>  expression in the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a
>   function call expression, or a sequence of preprocessing tokens in the
>   comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses in a function-like
>   macro invocation
>  
>   ...
>   **parameter
>  
>   formal parameter
>   formal argument (deprecated)**
>   object
>   declared as part of a function declaration
>   or definition that acquires a value on entry to the function, or an
>   identifier from the comma-separated list bounded by the parentheses
>   immediately following the macro name in a function-like macro
>   definition

Т.е. в аргументы непосредственно при вызове функции (использовании макроса) - *фактические*, а те, что в объявлении функции (макроса) - *формальные*.
Основываясь на этом приведу примеры:

```
#define MACRO(x, y) //x и y - формальные параметры (аргументы)    
void foo(int x, int y) //x и y - формальные параметры (аргументы)

//...

MACRO(2, z) //2 и z - актуальные (фактические) аргументы (параметры)
foo(2, z) //2 и z - актуальные (фактические) аргументы (параметры)
```